# Mudar o endereço do WCF no Windows Universal App do ambiente de desenvolvimento para o de produção

Tags: windows-phone, wcf, xaml, deploy

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em Universal Windows App (para Windows 10, Windows 10 Mobile, etc), que, basicamente esta aplicação faz o consumo de dados que estão que estão no serviço a correr em WCF.

Acontece que, eu possuo uma solução única em que lá tenho o serviço WCF e a minha aplicação Windows App.
Quando corro esta aplicação em ambiente de desenvolvimento, tudo corre perfeitamente, inclusive até, porque o serviço está a correr em local host.

O que me facilitaria seria o facto de ao fazer um Pulish do serviço, o sistema automaticamente trocasse as configurações de endereço de servidor para o de produção. O que no caso do WCF consegui

Só que o mesmo não consegui para o Windows App. Ou seja, gostaria de re-apontar o endereço do serviço do WCF dentro desta Windows App durante o processo de Deploying.

**Nota:** Já consegui fazer isto numa WebApp (Asp.MVC) em que basta apenas trocar o web.config

> A minha dúvida é, como faço isto numa Windows App do Windows 10 /
>   Windows Phone?

Sei perfeitamente que podia fazer isto de raíz durante o processo do Add Reference do Visual Studio, bastando apenas apontar o endereço do servidor de produção. Mas na prática isso não é muito fluído

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Tenho um WCF de teste e outro de Produção, como você. 
Desenvolvi uma aplicação WP8 que possui uma tela de configurações, entre outras informações tem a entrada da URI do WCF. 
A Uri está definida no app.xaml.cs e é gravada em um arquivo xml na isostore do aparelho.
Sempre que inicio a aplicação leio a URI do arquvo XML.
Se precisar reiniciar as configurações regravo as informações definadas no app.xaml.cs.

Espero que te ajude.

Abcs

:ioz

Comment: Sim, mas isso na prática não é tão fluído. Numa webApp isso é possível. Não vejo o porquê da dificuldade numa Windows App.